# Using imacro to click on ANALYZE Button

Tags: imacros

First of all I am new to imacro .I am trying to get a list of urls analyzed by Mobile-friendly Test Tool ,but I am not able to get a click on Analyze button using imacros.

[image]

I have tried to make it working using class,text as well as with Role, but could not get it working,

```
Method 1.TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:goog-inline-block<SP>jfk-button<SP>jfk-button-action<SP>analyze<SP>main-submit<SP>jfk-button-hover<SP>jfk-button-active<SP>jfk-button-focused<SP>jfk-button-clear-outline&&TXT:* 


Method 2.TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ROLE:button&&TXT:ANALYZE
```

so is there any other way I could make it working.Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must work:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#page-speed-insights>DIV>FORM>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
```